# Why is flutter unable to load asset image?

Tags: flutter, dart

No errors in the code and as far as I can see the pubspec.yaml file is functional, as it worked before.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Image.asset('anyaparent.jpeg'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Error text "Unable to load asset"]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeTW2.png]
[image: The pubspec.yaml file]

Comment: make sure to add images on `pubspec.yaml` and rebuild the app

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  whoops sorry, i added the pubspec.yaml i dont think theres anything wrong here

Comment: try `'images/anyaparent.jpeg',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing like this

```
Image.asset('images/anyaparent.jpeg'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your image `path images/anyaparent.jpeg`

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: Image.asset('images/anyaparent.jpeg'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```